# Laravel RESTful controller parameters

Tags: php, rest, xmlhttprequest, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4 with Angular JS to handle $http requests using RESTful controllers.

I have a RESTful controller, `UserController` that has the following functions:

```
public function getIndex(){
    //is Request::get() the correct way to get the parameter?
    echo json_encode(array(
      'username'=>User::countUsername(Request::get('name')),
      'email'=>User::countEmail(Request::get('email'))
    ));
}

public function postIndex(){
    //don't know how to get parameter
}
```

The $http GET and POST requests I am making are below:

GET

```
//is this url the correct way to send in my parameters for GET request?
dataString = 'name='+username+'&email='+email;
$http.get('user?'+dataString).success(
    //do something with returned json
)
```

POST

```
data = {
   'username':username,
   'email':email,
   'password':password
}
$http.post('user', data).success(
    //do something
)
```

The `getIndex()` method works just fine, although I have doubts on whether I am using the correct procedure.

With the above mentioned, I have two questions:

1. Is `Request::get()` the correct way to retrieve parameters from the XHR GET? Is appending `dataString` to the URL in my Javascript the correct way to send in parameters the RESTful way?
2. How do I retrieve the JSON object sent from my XHR POST? I have tried several methods including `Request::get()` and `Input::json()`, but I've had no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$input = Input::all()` to retrieve data send using angular $http. Then use like `$name = $input['name'];`

And if you are using updated Laravel 4, the best way to use RESTful API is,

The controller looks like this,

```
<?php


class UsersController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display all users.
     *
     * @return Response
     * GET http://localhost/laravel/users
     */

    public function index() {
        $users = User::all();
        return $users;
        //return View::make('users.index')->with('users', $users);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    public function create() {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     * POST http://localhost/laravel/users
     */

    public function store() {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     * GET http://localhost/laravel/users/1
     */

    public function show($id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */

    public function edit($id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     * PUT http://localhost/laravel/users/1
     */

    public function update($id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     * DELETE http://localhost/laravel/users/1
     */

    public function destroy($id) {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->delete();

        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => false,
            'message' => 'User Deleted'),
            200
        );
    }

}
```

In your route,

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

In angular script use,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
// include this in php page to define root path
app.factory('Data', function(){
    return {
        root_path: "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/"
    };
});
```

GET - Get all users

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: Data.root_path + 'users'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.users = data.users;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.users = [];
});
```

GET - Get single user for edit

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: Data.root_path + 'users/'+id}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.entry = data.users[0];
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.entry = [];
});
```

PUT - Update single user

```
$http.put(Data.root_path + 'users/'+entry.id, entry).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //
});
```

POST - Save new user

```
$http.post(Data.root_path + 'users', entry).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //
});
```

DELETE - Delete a user

```
$http.delete(Data.root_path +'users/'+id)
.success(function(response) { 
    //
})
.error(function(response) {
    //
});
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the answer. is it the route::resource that allows you to put in parameters after the forward slash?

Comment: Yes. for example in destroy function, I am passing the user id using forward slash in angular ``$http.delete``