# Laravel 4. default controller route wont accept arguments

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a RESTful controller for my users to handle the viewing of a users profile.

The problem is this:

I want the url to look like this `www.example.com/user/1`

This would show the user with the id of 1. The problem is that when i define the `getIndex` method in the UserController it wont accept the id as an argument.

Here is my routes.php portion:

```
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

Now, it is my understanding that getIndex is sort of the default route if nothing else is supplied in the url, and so this:

```
public function getIndex() {

}
```

within the UserController will accept routes,

```
"www.example.com/user/index"
```

and

```
"www.example.com/user"
```

and it does!

However, if I include an argument that it should take from the url, it no longer works:

```
public function getIndex($id) {
    //retrieve user info for user with $id
}
```

This will only respond to

```
"www.example.com/user/index/1"
```

and not

```
"www.example.com/user/1"
```

How can i make the latter work? I really do not want to clutter up the url with the word "index" if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do this, the best way is to use RESTful controllers.

Change your route to this one,

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Then generate a controller using `php artisan` command,

```
php artisan controller:make UserController
```

This will generate your controller with all RESTful functions,

```
<?php

class UserController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index() // url - GET /user (see all users)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create() 
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store() // url - POST /user (save new user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id) // url - GET /user/1 (edit the specific user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id) 
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id) // url - PUT /user/1 (update specific user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id) // url - DELETE /user/1 (delete specific user)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

For more info, see this one [Laravel RESTful controller parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196636/laravel-restful-controller-parameters/19196884#19196884)

Answer (score 0):

To display `www.example.com/user/1` on address bar you should use `show` method. In Laravel, restful controller by default create 7 routes. Show is one of them.

**in your controller create a method like the following:**

```
public function show($id) 
{
    // do something with id

    $user = User::find($id);
    dd($user);
}
```

Now, Browse `http://example.com/user/1`.

Comment: @devo. It was my understanding that such a controller was actually a resource controller, whereas a RESTful controller was one such that each function corresponds to an HTTP action and URI concatenated together. In this case, this: 

    `public function getProfile() {} `

in the user controller will respond to an HTTP GET request to

    `.com/user/profile`

My entire user controller is set up to to use this method and I would rather keep it that way. Is there no way to get it working without using a resource controller? or will simply including a show function in any controller work?